# Service worker fetch event is never fired

Tags: laravel-5.3, service-worker, progressive-web-apps, service-worker-events

I am developing Progressive Web Apps with Laravel. I have referred [PWA with Laravel](https://justmegareth.com/2017-07-15-progressive-web-app-in-laravel/) for developing. In that first I generated service worker, then updated laravel mix after that set manifest file. In the layout I checked for service worker and push notification support. After registering service worker, install and activate are successfully triggered but fetch event is never triggered even when the browser set to offline as in the image [browser offline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCQ5O.png). Also referred this video [PWA LARAVEL](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ts7jDVikaN4). Code for package.json file is as shown in the image: [package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cxfeo.png) code for webpack.config.js file is: [webpack.config.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AuRhB.png), section of code in the blade(view) for registering service worker is:[service-worker registration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vTQMg.png). Service worker is generated in public folder of my laravel project. I am new to Laravel and PWA. Thank you.

Comment: Have you checked a HTTPS URL with the chrome lighthouse audit dev tools? That may give you some clues.

Comment: I did the audit it asks to use service-worker to work offline, but I am already using service worker.

Comment: Can you share the URL you are using for the audit tool?
If not, what was the exact message under which item in the report?

Comment: It is showing message as "Does not respond with a 200 when offline
:If you're building a Progressive Web App, consider using a service worker so that your app can work offline".

Comment: Probably not finding/loading your service worker.

Comment: In the Chrome dev tools look under Application > Service Workers. Unregister any old ones you may see and also use the Clear Storage button.

Comment: Make sure you are checking with a HTTPS server, not localhost

Comment: Also try some console.log statements in the code where you are registering the service worker

Comment: Most likely you are never getting to the registration line of code listed in the image you attached

Comment: I had done clear storage, but it doesn't work. Server worker is registered and in service worker install and activate is working, only fetch is not loading.

Comment: Actually i am checking with localhost not htttps server.

Comment: Service worker is registered properly. After registration, install and activation is working properly.

Comment: I have seen a couple of demos where they recommend not doing the registration of the service worker locally. Things just get goofy there with cached items. All of the Angular apps by default prevent you from doing so:

Comment: Only Register in Production:   ServiceWorkerModule.register('/ngsw-worker.js', { enabled: environment.production })

Comment: May work with Laravel? Sorry I am not familar with it's internals

Comment: If you have something small you can push out, try https://Glitch.me - Just make sure you change your URL to HTTPS for testing.

Comment: Is it not possible to use localhost instead of https??

Comment: I have referred: https://medium.com/codingthesmartway-com-blog/angular-5-service-worker-b722e571e306 this site is it the correct way?

Comment: In this youtube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ts7jDVikaN4 , they have registered it locally and did everything same as I did, there it works offline.

Comment: medium.com/codingthesmartway-com-blog/… Note that they also only do the service worker in production "Important to note is that fact that the service worker registration is only done by calling ServiceWorkerModule.register(‘/ngsw-worker.js’) only if we’re in production mode (if environment.production is true)."

Comment: Sorry, I have only tested my service worker using https since that is what I have seen in demos

Comment: Can you tell me how to test service worker using https instead of localhost in laravel?

Comment: @Mathias i have found the solution for what I asked, then it worked fine in offline. But after some time when i check in offline, its showing error as "This site can’t be reached. The web page at http:// url might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address. ERR_FAILED". In lighthouse audit dev tools, "Does not respond with a 200 when offline" is passed now and also install,activate,fetch is working fine. Only cache storage is getting empty during offline. Can you help me to fix the error.

Comment: Have you 1. uploaded code to an HTTPS URL 2. Confirmed with Lighthouse that "user can install" 3. Added to the home screen?

Comment: Yes. Actually that same file I copied and pasted to another file with different name and there it works fine. I don't know what is the issue but other places it works fine. **Thank you**..

Comment: If you can share the url, I could try it on my device to see if it works offline for me.

Comment: Its fixed now. Thank you.

Comment: @Mathias can you suggest some solution for this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51759436/how-to-trigger-a-push-event-in-service-worker ?

Comment: No sorry, I haven't played with push notifications yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer. Actually in my laravel project I had removed public from url. But service worker will receive fetch events for everything on its domain; that is if we register the service worker file at /example/sw.js, then the service worker would only see fetch events for pages whose URL starts with /example/ (i.e. /example/page1/, /example/page2/). So I should change my url pattern to public. Thank you.